# Why can't I build this Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object I'm trying to populate from another object (that is, iterate over a return object to produce an object with only selected values from the original). My code looks like this:

```
var collect = {};

function getHistoricalData(username){
$.getJSON("http://url/" + username + ".json?params",
            function(data){
                for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    console.log(i);
                    collect = { i : {text : data[i].text}};
                    $("#wrap").append("<span>" + data[i].text + "</span><br />");

                };
                console.log(collect);
            }); 

}
```

So I'm using Firebug for debugging, and here's what I know:

- The JSON object is intact
- `console.log(i);` is showing the numbers 1-20 as expected
- When I log the `collect` object at the end, it's structure is this:
  `var collect = { i : {text : "the last iteration's text"}};`

  So the incrementer is "applying" to the data[i].text and returning the text value, but it's not doing what I expected, which is create a new member of the collect object; it's just overwriting `collect.i` 20 times and leaving me with the last value.

Is there a different syntax I need to be using for assigning object members? I tried `collect.i.text =` and `collect[i].text =` and the error was that whatever I tried was undefined.

I'd love to know what's going on here, so the more in-depth an explanation the better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing only one property in the object at the end is that you're not augmenting it in each loop iteration - you're overwriting it.

`collect = { i : {text : data[i].text}};`

This says: create an object with one property, `i`, whose value is another object with one property, `text`, and assign it to the variable `collect`. What you want to do instead is set a property of the existing `collect` object for each value of `i`, where `i` is the name of the property.

In order to create an object property where the name is set dynamically, you must use array-style syntax, like this: `collect[i]`. I don't think you can mix array syntax and object literal syntax like you've tried. Try this instead (disclaimer, not tested):

`collect[i] = { text: data[i]["text"] };`

Comment: Edited to explain what's going on. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 collect[i] = {text : data[i].text};
```

If you use `collect[i].text`, since `collect[i]` does not exist before the assignment, it will return `undefined`, which has no `text` property.

Also:

1. `collect.i` means `collect["i"]`. This is totally different from `collect[i]`.
2. You can use an Array and append with `.push`.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, the problem is in this line:

```
 collect = { i : {text : data[i].text}};
```

Every iteration of the loop, you are erasing the collect object and assigning it a new object as value. That's why in the end it only shows the last iteration.

Try this:

```
 collect[i] = {text : data[i].text};
```